# Laravel with trashed specified ID

Tags: laravel

Exist a way to make a Eloquent Query with trashed but only get a specify ID trashed and all query withoutTrashed?

For example:

I have 15 products in total in database, 10 are not deleted and 5 are trashed.

I do `Product::withTrashed()->get()` it show 15 products, it is OK.

But what happen if the product with id 11 is trash and I need the others 10 products plus this trash.

Exist a way to do something like `Product::withTrash(11)->get()` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a direct method like `withTrash(11)->get()` in Eloquent, but you can achieve the same result with a little bit more complex query. The way to do this is by using the `withTrashed()` method in combination with a where clause.

Here's an example:

```
Product::where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('id', 11)
          ->withTrashed();
})->orWhere(function ($query) {
    $query->where('id', '<>', 11);
})->get();
```

In this example, the first part of the query checks for the product with the ID of 11, including trashed items. The second part (orWhere) gets all the products that aren't trashed and don't have an ID of 11.

This will give you all the non-trashed products plus the product with ID 11 (whether it's trashed or not).